# How do I define the Abp language to use during unit test execution?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am creating unit tests for my service layer.  I used the existing  UserAppService_Tests test that comes with the downloaded template as a guide.

However I am seeing this exception thrown.

```
Abp.AbpException : No language defined!
```

My Test inherits from `GpTestBase` which in turn inherits from  `AbpIntegratedTestBase<GpTestModule>`

GpTestModule has :

**Configuration.Modules.Zero().LanguageManagement.EnableDbLocalization();**

So I thought that it should be ok.

Any clues?

```
 public override void PreInitialize()
        {
            Configuration.UnitOfWork.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            Configuration.UnitOfWork.IsTransactional = false;

            // Disable static mapper usage since it breaks unit tests (see https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2052)
            Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().UseStaticMapper = false;

            Configuration.BackgroundJobs.IsJobExecutionEnabled = false;

            // Use database for language management
            Configuration.Modules.Zero().LanguageManagement.EnableDbLocalization();

            RegisterFakeService<AbpZeroDbMigrator<GpDbContext>>();

            Configuration.ReplaceService<IEmailSender, NullEmailSender>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be defining the language to use explicitly.

To have a localization context, you should **login as a user**.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you don't have any languages defined in the `AbpLanguages` table. Example [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/1192#issuecomment-317493854).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by `public const bool MultiTenancyEnabled = true;`. Changing MultiTenancyEnabled to **false**, solved the problem.